# What are "Paris standards"? Help me figure out what they mean here

Tags: sql-server

I read a job description for a SQL database and web application developer position.  They said that the code and technical documents I write should meet "Paris standards."

Can someone explain what Paris standards are?  That is, what are they talking about here?  I don't think I have seen this term before.

I have run a Google search and could not find a definite answer, thus, why I am asking the experts here what the meaning of this term is.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an autocorrect issue in the description.

Comment: Almost certainly a typo.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments almost certainly a typo.  Assuming they intended you to use [PEAR standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I am pretty sure you have the right answer.